# Dynamic parameters for sql query with "IN" operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

I have an ASP.NET website (c#) and in the code-behind I want to use the `IN` operator in SQL http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp to get data from my database.

The syntax is:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...)
```

I use a stored procedure to get data, inside this procedure I run, in the end, the select.

My question is how to build dynamically the (`value1, value2, ...`) part of the query? How do I send as `SqlParameter`(s) the values that appear in the `IN` operator?

The stored procedure is defined like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllUsers]
    @ORGANIZATION_ID int = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    begin
       SELECT * 
       from USERS
       where ORGANIZATION_ID = @ORGANIZATION_ID
    end
END
```

I'd like to replace the `WHERE` clause with something like:

```
WHERE ORGANIZATION in (xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

How to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: what DBMS (SQLServer/MySQL/Oracle) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllUsers]
    @ORGANIZATION_ID varchar(max) = null
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql varchar(max)
    @sql = 'SELECT * 
            from USERS
            where ORGANIZATION_ID in ('+@ORGANIZATION_ID+')' 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        begin
          exec(@sql)  
        end
END
```

You have to change type of `@ORGANIZATION_ID` to varchar and run the procedure with

one id:

```
exec '1'
```

or list of ids:

```
exec '1,2,3,4'
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I use ORGANIZATION_ID varchar(max) or ORGANIZATION_ID varchar(10000).

Comment: It's bad practice to do so, however

Comment: @Sklivvz Can you tell me, what is better practice? I will consider it, then I will add new solution.